# How to determine why a C# event is firing too many times

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

I have a .NET class that subscribes to an event by using this line:

```
SecurityComponent.GcsRightsUpdated += SecurityComponent_GcsRightsUpdated;
```

This is a very big host application with many plugged in components. I know which method of the SecurityComponent is called that fires this event (DoUpdateSecurityVariables). The problem is that I do not know which class is calling *this* method.

When I put a breakpoint in this method and look at the Stack Trace, it shows that it is an anonymous method that calls it but I do not know which code is calling this. The rest of the stack trace I do not understand, it is not our code. I need to know this because it is being called many many times, and I need to get to the bottom of why it is being fired so many times.

Here is the stack trace from Visual Studio:

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: DoubleClick on the StackTrace entry with the AnonymousMethod in the debugger and you will teleported there.

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, I did that, but I cannot tell who called the method that this line belongs to.

Comment: Maybe you can show us the code of this method?